# How to join two tables on multiple columns using OR condition in bigquery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Lets say I have two tables.
First table shown below:

`tableA`

[image]

Second table
`tableB`

[image]

Now I want to write a query That will join the two tables above on either name OR email OR phone.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
ON
(tableA.name_A = tableB.name_B OR tableA.email_A = tableB.email_B OR tableA.phone_A = tableB.phone_B)
```

And it should produce a table something like this

[image]

If you notice,

1. John matches rows between tableA and tableB on name.
2. Ally/allie matches rows between tableA and tableB on email.
3. Sam/Samual matches rows between tableA and tableB on phone

When I try to do this same query though I receive an
error that says LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.

I am using BigQuery.
Please help, cheers

Comment: was there specific reason you tried LEFT JOIN vs INNER JOIN? looks like there is some extra logic behind this that is not exposed in  your question :o)

Answer (score 2):

Try `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON
(tableA.name_A = tableB.name_B OR tableA.email_A = tableB.email_B OR tableA.phone_A = tableB.phone_B)
```

or `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
CROSS JOIN tableB
WHERE
    tableA.name_A = tableB.name_B
    OR tableA.email_A = tableB.email_B
    OR tableA.phone_A = tableB.phone_B
```

or `UNION DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
ON tableA.name_A = tableB.name_B
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
ON tableA.email_A = tableB.email_B
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
ON tableA.phone_A = tableB.phone_B
```

Answer (score 1):

could you try by using parenthesis

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
ON
(tableA.name_A = tableB.name_B) OR 
(tableA.email_A = tableB.email_B) OR
 (tableA.phone_A = tableB.phone_B)
```